# Where can I get challenging exercises for Naive Set Theory by Halmos?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request

the title says it all. I am just filling in the 30 characters required amount.

Comment: [Here](https://www.amazon.com/Exercises-Set-Theory-L-Sigler/dp/0387901930/ref=dp_ob_title_bk)? Or [here](https://www.scribd.com/document/335233388/Solutions-Manual-to-Naive-Set-Theory-by-Paul-Halmos)? Or [here](https://kupdf.net/download/solutions-manual-to-naive-set-theory-by-paul-halmos_59905dd5dc0d608d65300d1b_pdf)?

Comment: thanks. I am once again filling in the required amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a book by L. E. Sigler, *Exercises in Set Theory*, that is explicitly designed to follow Halmos. The exercises range from the routine to some that are more challenging. If this is too easy for you, then I recommend checking out Komjáth & Totik's *Problems and Theorems in Classical Set Theory*, which is considerably more challenging. Both books contain answers to the exercises.